# jquery changing a generated object

Tags: jquery

I have an object like so:

`Object {ABC-123: "XYZ", ABC-112: "LAX"}`

and it is generated like so:

```
 var editObject = {};

        $.each(editHolder, function (index, value) {
            editObject[value] = $('#' + value).val();
        });
```

I need to change my object so it looks like so:

`[ { job: "ABC-123", task: "XYZ" },  { job: "ABC-333", task: "LAX" }]`

how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your `editHolder` iteration function to something like this should do it:

```
var editArray = [];

$.each(editHolder, function (index, value) {
    editArray.push({ job: value, task: $('#' + value).val() });
});
```

Or if you need to convert it after the fact, this should work:

```
var myArray = [];

for (var key in editObject ) {
    myArray.push( {job:key, editObject[key]} );
}
```